# Multi-GPU Batch Normalization in Torch

Tags: deep-learning, nvidia, torch, multi-gpu

Does torch synchronize the `running_mean` and `running_var` between the clones present in the N GPUs during a multi-GPU training? It is being said that any Torch module that goes into `nn.DataParallelTable` is optimized by the usage of NVIDIAs `nccl` library.

But a few people claim that Torch doesn't synchronize the `running_mean` and `running_var`. I'd be really glad if someone shed some clarity on this topic.